# Calculate capacitance given I and V graphs

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, capacitance, passive-networks

There's this question which asked us to find the capacitance value give both (v-t) and (i-t) graphs for capacitor.

Here are the graphs:

[image: Current-time graph]

[image: Voltage-Time]

---

This is how I calculated the capacitance:

It was obvious from the graphs that the value of \$ \tau = 0.2s \$ and \$ i_0 = 0.1mA \$.

This is how I setup the equation:

\$ \Rightarrow v(1) = \frac{1}{C}\ \int_{0}^{1} i(t)\ dt+v_0 \$ 
 \$ \Rightarrow 1v = \frac{1}{C}\ \int_{0}^{1} 0.1m\ e^{-5t}dt+0 \$ 
 \$ \Rightarrow C = 0.1mA\ \int_{0}^{1} e^{-5t}dt \$ 
 \$ \Rightarrow C = 0.1mA\ \frac{1}{5}\ [-e^{-5t}\ ] \big\vert_{0}^1 \$ 
 \$ \Rightarrow C = 20 \mu F \$

That's how I find capacitance. Now there's a comment from a guy who gave me a hint but I am not able to understand what he want to say, he said:

> One graph tells you the initial current is 0.1mA and the other graph tells you that  the final voltage = 1.0V.  What does that imply about the series resistance?  Now you know R and t, so you can find C.

I have no clue, what he meant by series resistance and why initial current and final voltage.  Aren't those the conditions I already used in the integral?

Comment: If you charge the capacitor with a constant current the voltage across the capacitor will be ramping up linearly. But your graph is showing exponential charing thus, we have a resistor in series with the capacitor.

Comment: If you would insert the numbers into your formula, you wouldn't get 20 micro., because it wrong. The final voltage is reached in infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't look your solution in detail, but it is very simple:

$$R=\dfrac{V}{I}=\dfrac{1}{0.1\cdot 10^{-3}}=10k\Omega$$

$$C=\dfrac{\tau}{R}=\dfrac{0.2}{10000}=20\mu F$$

Comment: i m sorry but why did you taken final voltage value and initial current? i mean you could've take both value at same corresponding time

Comment: @fpsshubham At beginning, there is 0V over capacitor, but full 1V over resistor, and full 0.1mA through resistor.

Comment: @Justme ok i get it i think.... current stopped because voltage across resistor become 0 that tells us  source must be of 1v... and at starting capacitor acted like short ckt

Comment: @fpsshubham I don't understand the downvote, At t=0, the capacitor is SC so the entire current is limited by the resistor. At the end you do know the initial voltage 1V.

Comment: Not my downvote but it might be for doing OP's homework for them. (I've gotten a lot of those downvotes too, even for giving a hint without doing the complete problem)

Answer (score 1):

> I have no clue, what he meant by series resistance and why initial
> current and final voltage. Aren't those the conditions I already used
> in the integral?

He is suggesting a much simpler way to calculate the capacitance.

The graph suggests that the capacitor is charging to a fixed supply voltage through a resistor. If so then \$R = v_s/i_0\$ and you can use the [RC time constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant) formula \$t=RC\$ to calculate \$C\$.